# Can having other coronaviruses like HCoV-OC43 give positive results when testing for SARS-CoV-2?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, infectious-diseases, test, sars-cov-2

Is it possible that a person having coronaviruses other than SARS-CoV-2 test positive for SARS-CoV-2 in rapid (antibody testing kits) as well as RT PCR tests? Searching around the internet didn't yield any insight about this.My logic behind the question is,if the viruses are similar,shouldn't they show positive when tested for one?

Comment: What prior research have you done?

Comment: What do you mean by "rapid"? Antibodies tests? Some RT PCR tests have also been described as "rapid" by their manufacturers https://hitconsultant.net/2020/04/23/in-depth-32-fda-approved-covid-19-testing-kits

Comment: @GrahamChiu just searched how does testing methodology works.@Fizz yes many of the chinese rapid testing kits seems to be antibody testing kits